# How to display distinct column values into drop down list MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So here is the deal, I have a table Audits, this table contains column "Status" which specifies the Audit current Status. Now I am creating a view to search this table, one of the fields will be the Status which I would like to grab from the database and display it in an drop down list for the user to choose from.

This is how I create the SelectList in the Controller:

```
            ViewBag.Audit_Status = new SelectList(db.Audits, "Audit_Status", "Audit_Status");
```

And When I create my drop down list in the view:

```
                @Html.DropDownList("Audit_Status", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The problem is that I get the Statuses duplicated because obviously there are multiple Audits have the same Status. How can I only show Distinct status ?

Comment: I am looking for a solution other than:
1- Creating a separate table for the status 
2- Creating a hard-coded status IEnumerable and using it in the SelectList

Comment: What is `db` in this context?

Comment: Use LINQ for distinct operation for a column inside data context like `db.Audits.Select(x => x.Status).Distinct();`. Then you need to attach SelectList on DDL helper argument for adding option items.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I did't understand what do you mean about DDL helper

Comment: DDL helper means selectlist intelisense to build selectlist with data, displaytext and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **distinct** in LINQ :

```
ViewBag.Audit_Status = new SelectList(db.Audits.Select(m => m.Audit_Status).Distinct(), "Audit_Status", "Audit_Status");
```

**For Optional Text:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Audit_Status", null, "Please specify the Status", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: It didn't work, keeps throwing this error
 DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Audit_Status'.

Comment: You have give code in that you have mention "Audit_Status" column, please replace that column which you retrieve and wants to display

Comment: It is not the problem , I have posted what was wrong, thanks for your help. But I have another quick question, now when I send the data to the SelectList is it possible that the first selected value which appears to user be a value not from the database, something like "Please specify the Status"

Comment: There is one property of option value you can specify there "Please specify the Status"

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean "one property of option value"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sandip and @codelahiru

Using Linq to query distinct as both have commented

```
ViewBag.Audit_Status = new SelectList(db.Audits.Select (x => x.Audit_Status).Distinct());
```

However, When you are selecting the data from only one column you can't specify the data value field and the data text field, if you do so, the view will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will fix your issue.

```
ViewBag.Audit_Status == db.Audits.Select(x => x.Audit_Status)
                                             .Distinct()
                                             .Select(x =>
                                             new SelectList
                                             {
                                                 Text = x,
                                                 Value = x
                                             }).ToList();
```

or if you will be using linq a lot in your code.Then you can install MoreLinq nuget.DistinctBy is one of the very useful extension in MoreLinq.

```
ViewBag.Audit_Status == db.Audits.DistinctBy(x => x.Audit_Status)                                                 
                                             .Select(x =>
                                             new SelectList
                                             {
                                                 Text = x.Audit_Status,
                                                 Value = x.Audit_Status//you can give any value
                                             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `db.Audits` is your *status* list, then Use `linq` command like this,

```
ViewBag.Audit_Status = new SelectList(db.Audits.Distinct(), "Audit_Status", "Audit_Status");
```

Or if `Audits` has any properties inside it like `Status` use your linq like this,'

```
ViewBag.Audit_Status = new SelectList(db.Audits.Select(x=>x.Status).Distinct().ToList(), "Audit_Status", "Audit_Status");
```

Comment: Someone who downgraded my answer, please provide a comment about that, Because there may be something I can learn too..